# Sentiment Analysis using OpenNLP

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis, opennlp

I am using Apache OpenNLP for Sentiment Analysis on Yammer conversations.  The idea here is to classify each conversation to positive, negative or neutral sentiment. A conversation can be a single sentence or a group of sentences.

I have 2 models - a short sentence classifying model and a long sentence classifying model.  The short sentence classifying model is trained with shorter sentences (less than 10 words) with a cutoff of 2 and the long sentence classifying model is trained with longer sentences with a cutoff of 5.

Here is my approach

1. Read each conversation.
2. Cleanse it to remove HTTP URLs, special characters, add a space after dot etc.
3. Use SentenceDetector to split the conversation into sentences.
4. For each sentence call classification. If the sentence is short then short sentence classification model is called or else long sentence classification model is called. The output of  sentence classification is positive, negative or neutral
5. Sum up the results of sentence classification. i.e if more positive sentences are found then classify conversation as positive else negative or neutral accordingly.

I have a couple of questions related to this approach

1. Do I need two models a short sentence model and a long sentence model. The reason I decided to do this is because cutoff for a shorter sentence and longer sentence are different.
2. Is it ok to follow a sentence based classification model and then sum up the results of each sentence to get the result of the conversation.
3. Is there a standard/better approach to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approach is valid...trying to build sentiment models on large chunks of text is problematic, so the sentence based approach seems like a good idea to me.

As for the long and short sentence models, that seems like a good idea, assuming there is a large enough difference ("usually") between the content in a short as opposed to long sentence. You may also consider a different featuregenerator for the longer sentence model...sometimes ngrams (word bigrams) work well to help contextualize the content a bit more than the normal Bag of words approach.

As for the output, rolling up a sum might be a little too hard to normalize, due to an unknown amount of sentences in each thread (maybe...), so I would consider doing basic stats (min, max, sum, avg, stdev, majority) for each class of each model so you can ask better questions of the results (for example, you could write the results to an index for fuzzy discovery that would enable multiple use cases)

HTH